# Make SortedDict sorted by values in Julia

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia and I've noticed it's not easy to Google for things which seem to be little more beyond elementary.

I would like to create an instance of [SortedDict](https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/v0.9/sorted_containers.html#Constructors-for-Sorted-Containers-1) from [DataStructures](https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/v0.9/index.html) package but I want it to be sorted by values.

According to the documentation, the SortedDict takes parameter `o` which is some kind of comparator (order), so I guess I should create the one which does what I want.

```
SortedDict(o=Forward)
```

After some search, I've found how the `Forward` ordering is programmed [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/ordering.jl) and I must admit it's hard to decipher for me.

I wanna have an instance of such a dict: SortedDict{String,Float64} and I want it to be sorted according to these Float64s.
Example:

```
(
    "b" => 0.1,
    "a" => 0.2,
    "c" => 0.3
)
```

Could someone please tell me if this is possible and if so please indicate the solution?

Comment: Please elaborate what you're asking, perhaps with an example of expected output. Are you using "value" in a general sense, or in opposition to "key"?

Comment: @phipsgabler You are right, when I was writing this it was clear but for others it will not be.

Comment: Is the dictionary going to be mutated?  If not, storing the order separately is easy.

Comment: I need to be able to add a pair (String,Float64) in the correct place several times and then pop it to keep the specific size. For now, I use OrderedDict which is recreated each time I add some portion of these pairs. To give a context, I want a top rank list in a genetic algorithm where strings correspond to chromosomes and floats to scores. I hope, now it is more clear.

Comment: I know that there are several different ways to have it working but I want it to be efficient and clean simultaneously. Just wondering if it is possible in Julia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SortedDict` type does seem to support sorting by value. An alternative could be to use `OrderedDict` from the [OrderedCollections](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/OrderedCollections.jl) package (it is also reexported by the DataStructures package). It is ordered by insertion order, but it does allow you to sort it by value:

```
julia> o = OrderedDict("a" => 0.2, "b" => 0.1, "c" => 0.3)
OrderedDict{String,Float64} with 3 entries:
  "a" => 0.2
  "b" => 0.1
  "c" => 0.3

julia> sort(o, byvalue=true)
OrderedDict{String,Float64} with 3 entries:
  "b" => 0.1
  "a" => 0.2
  "c" => 0.3
```